# SQL obtaining evenly distributed values from multiple groups

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this table in MySQL:

[image: colors by group]

And I need a query to obtain a result like this:

[image: desired result]

As you can see, the group are in a 123,123,.. sequence. If some group doesn't have any more rows, it is skipped.

The order of the items in each group is not important, as soon as they are distinct.

Thank you!!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the advice. it's my first post

Answer (score 2):

This works in MySql 8.0. You mentioned the order of the colors doesn't matter, and this returns the order-by you seek (1-2-3, 1-2-3, etc).

```
    select groupid, color
    from (
        select groupid, color, 
        rank() over (partition by groupid order by color) as grouprank
        from table1)z
    order by grouprank, groupid
```

dbfiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5DXNToRUNoonych1cjekph/0